# Angular-material calendar with custom class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-material

At Angular [UI Bootstrap directive](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) you can add customClass function that give any date a class according to the user decision.

[image]

My question is: Can I do the same thing with the [material calendar](https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.3/api/directive/mdCalendar)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no possibility to do that "out of box", but you can redefine CSS for this directive:

1. Add some custom class to your BODY tag (calendar renders into it)
2. Check *datepicker-default-theme.css* and *datepicker.css* from angular-material package
3. Write your own CSS-file which uses that custom style as a parent container for the new rules.

   ```
   body.customClass {
      ...
   }
   ```